# I want to create array problem using python

Tags: python, arrays

You all have seen how to write loops in python. Now is the time to implement what you have learned.

Given an array A of N numbers, you have to write a program which prints the sum of the elements of array A with the corresponding elements of the reverse of array A.
If array A has elements [1,2,3], then reverse of the array A will be [3,2,1] and the resultant array should be [4,4,4].

Input Format:

The first line of the input contains a number N representing the number of elements in array A.
The second line of the input contains N numbers separated by a space. (after the last elements, there is no space)

Output Format:

Print the resultant array elements separated by a space. (no space after the last element)

Example:

Input:
4
2 5 3 1

Output:
3883

Explanation:
Here array A is [2,5,3,1] os reverse of this array is [1,3,5,2] and hence the resultant array is [3,8,8,3]

My solution is not working.

my solution is:

```
r=input()
r=int(r)
result_t = []
d=[]
for i in range(0, r):
    c=input()
    c=int(c)
    t = i
    result_t.append(c)
d=reversed(result_t)
d=int(d)
s=result_t+d
for i in range(0, r):
       print(s[i])
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: @tyteen4a03, In several ways.

Comment: Who are you talking to on the first line? What do you mean by " Now is the time to implement what you have learned."? It sounds like you just copied that from a tutorial.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Please share the error messages that you are getting. =)

Comment: `d=int(d)` makes no sense. You can't convert a list to an integer. And why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over both `result_t` and `d`. You can use `zip()` to combine two lists so you can loop over them in parallel:

```
r=input()
r=int(r)
result_t = []
for i in range(r):
    c=input()
    c=int(c)
    result_t.append(c)
d = reversed(result_t)
result = [x + y for x, y in zip(result_t, d)]
print(result.join(" "))
```

You can also do it without making the reversed list.

```
result = [x + result_t[-(i+1)] for i, x in enumerate(result_t)]
```

When you use a negative index in a list, it counts from the end. You have to add 1 before negating, because the last element is `-1` (since `-0` is the same as `0`, which is the first element).

Answer (score 0):

"can only concatenate list (not "list_reverseiterator") to list"

reversed(result_t) returns not the list but iterator

**try:**

```
rev = []
for i in reversed(result_t):
    rev.append(i)
print(rev)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
   x = input()
   result_t = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
   rev = [x for x in reversed(result_t)]
   result = [int(x) + int(y) for x, y in zip(result_t, rev)]
   for i in result:
      print(i,end=" ")
```

Comment: explain why your answer is different than others and it helps questioner and others to better understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here array A is `[2,5,3,1]` and reverse of this array is `[1,3,5,2]` and hence the resultant array is `[3,8,8,3]`.

```py
a = []
n = int(input("Enter the number of elements"))
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input("Enter the elements"))
    a.append(x)

print(a)

res = []
b = [None] * len(a)
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    b[i] = a[i]
b.reverse()
print(b)

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    res.append(a[i] + b[i])
print(res)
```

Comment: The second for loop could be replaced with `b = a.copy()` or `b = a[:]`.